# Persistance of review number on top bar even after review is complete

Tags: feature-request, review

Say, I've got 3 posts for review. After I've reviewed all three, the top bar still shows that 3 posts are up for review. Now, if I go and click the review button, I just get a screen saying that there are no posts for reviewing.

This whole system is confusing and misleading to the user. As and when I review a post, the counter on the top bar should get decremented dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

What @Oli explained is only valid for 10k+ users. Being at 2.2k rep, you only see suggested edits.

The review process in SE all happens using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Which basically means that, each time you do an action, only parts of the website is reloaded, not all of it. Another example is when you vote up/down, add a comment, etc.

So in any case, when you are done reviewing, that number above will not be reset unless you reload the page.

To check it, during your review process, try to open the site in a new tab/window or just reload the page. You will see that number is different that what you started with.
Could be more, could be less depending if someone had suggested new edits.

Answer (score 0):

They show different things

- The bar number shows the total posts awaiting review. Even after you've reviewed something, other people need to corroborate that. It's a team effort.
- The review page shows posts that you *can* review. You can only review things once.

I can see how it would be confusing and I don't disagree that the bar should probably show the same thing, I'm just explaining what's what.

Comment: Sub 10k users only see suggested edits.

Comment: @seth - why? I might actually bother to review more than the suggested edits then...

Comment: @Wilf tbh, I don't really know. The indicator I see is just the total number of all review tasks in the system and only links to the /review page. I find it pretty pointless.