# Meta AU says I have one suggested edit to review, but I have none, how come?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-queue

Meta AU (even after refreshing the page) says that I have 1 suggested edit to review:

[image]

However there is no suggested edit to be seen if I click on the `1`, and the `1` still does not go away, even after I see there is no suggested edit:

[image]

How come it says there is one when there is not? Is it it that I simply cannot see it for some reason (this does not happen on the main site, nor can I see a `1` currently there, or any number)?

Comment: This is because you have just cleared the queue, once you refresh the page (Or go to some other page that requires a page reload) the number will be updated.

Comment: Does this help? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11733/persistance-of-review-number-on-top-bar-even-after-review-is-complete